# How to find and replace everything but numbers?

Tags: regex, replace, coldfusion, sybase

Hello everyone I have field where user can enter dollar amount. I use JQuery mask plugin to format the number. Here is example of the values that user enters in the input field:

```
30,000.00
7,513.12
100,324.23
90,234,232.34
```

Before I save the value in database I would like to remove all characters but numbers (period and commas in this case). I use `ColdFusion 2018` and function `reReplace()` for this purpuse. Here is example of what I have:

```
reReplace(form.amount, ".\,", "", "all")
```

The function above will provide these outputs:

```
30000.00
7513.12
100324.23
90234232.34
```

As you can see period is still not removed. Is there a way to get rid of everything but numbers?

Comment: `reReplace(form.amount, "[.,]", "", "all")`, `reReplace(form.amount, "[^0-9]", "", "all")`

Comment: Duplicate of [Need a regex to remove everything except numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772805/need-a-regex-to-remove-everything-except-numbers)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fyi... would be a good idea to add those in an answer instead of comment

Comment: If you are inserting into a database, what is the datatype in the db? Do you store the entire number as an integer? Sybase has a `money` datatype, and it would probably be better to use that. What happens of someone enters just `$30,000`? That's a lot different than stripping characters from `$30,000.00`.

Comment: @Shawn I have INTEGER datatype for the amount field. Also, I mentioned that I use JQuery mask on the front end to format the number. Scenario that you explained would be if someone tries to hack front end. That would lead to the situation where number would probably has wrong format.

Comment: Using front end js to validate data asks for trouble. Someone doesn't have to "hack". All that needs to happen is they have Javascript disabled/blocked/disallowed/limited. Regardless, is there a business need to run as `INTEGER`? You're usually better off using the datatype intended for the type of data you're using. If you're working with a value that has a decimal component, use a datatype that deals with decimals.

Comment: @Shawn If I change from INTEGER to DECIMAL(13,2) should I still trim the values as I showed in my example above before values get to the database? Thank you.

Comment: Leave the decimals in. But you'd probably also want to clean them up on server-side before trying to insert them.

Comment: @Shawn That's exactly what I asked. On the server side value should be just a number. If value submitted looks like this `8,500.00` then before value gets saved to db it should look like this 850000, correct?

Comment: I wouldn't. I'd submit `8500.00` to a decimal datatype.